# How to convert a generated word document using Docxtemplater to PDF?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, pdf, ms-word

Hello everyone I am currently developing a website using Angular.js where I would like to generate a word document from the user's input and thats worked just fine with!!

The problem is I want to let the user preview and download the word document as a PDF document
Hence i tried changing the MIME type and changing  the SaveAs format however it didn't work

I have also tried changing the word to PDF using packages with no luck so far

Here is the code for saving the generated word doc

```
this.loadFile("/assets/document/Template.docx", function(
  error,
  content
) {
  if (error) {
   console.log("Load file error: ",error) ;
  }
  var zip = new PizZip(content);
  var doc = new Docxtemplater().loadZip(zip);
doc.setData({
  tag: "Hello"
});
try {
   
        doc.render();
      } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
      }
       var out = doc.getZip().generate({
        type: "blob",
        mimeType:
        //"application/pdf;charset=utf-8"
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
      }); //Output the document using Data-URI

     saveAs(out, "GeneratedDocx.docx");
    });
  }
```

and i still can't use the out variable to convert using docxConverter or any other package

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code?

Comment: @bsheps yes sure

Comment: @TeamSiete did you find any solution? If yes please share

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my project while using docxtemplater. The following thing worked for me. I used docx-pdf npm package to convert it into a pdf.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-pdf

```
    var doc = new Docxtemplater()
    .attachModule(imageModule)
    .loadZip(zip)
    .setData(finalData)
    .render();

  var buffer = await doc.getZip().generate({ type: "nodebuffer" });

  fs.writeFile(outputPath, buffer, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(err.response, 401));
    }
  });
  
  docxConverter(outputPath,'./output.pdf',function(err,result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('result'+result);
  });
```

Conversion is not that accurate but it works in many cases for me. There are also some APIs available but they provide free for limited number of times.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested [in a parallel thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77694464/9225626), with `libreoffice-convert` there is no need at all to persist to a disk DOCX or PDF files. But a downside is that you need LibreOffice installed on the serving machine.

But don't install the full GUI version of LibreOffice, [use the lightweight headless version](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417164): `apt install -y libreoffice-nogui`.

Here is the code:

```
// In your controller or service:

export const exportTextToFile = async (text: string, filetype: string): Promise<Blob> => {
    const exportToFileEndpointUrl = `${API_BASE_URL}/api/export/${filetype}`;
    const response = await axios.post<ArrayBuffer>(exportToFileEndpointUrl, text, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    });

    return new Blob([response.data]);
};



// In your component:

const getAndDownloadFile = async (filetype: string) => {
        try {
            const blob = await exportTextToFile(text, filetype);
            saveAs(blob, `MyFile.${filetype}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };
```

In NodeJS backend app:

```
import libre from 'libreoffice-convert';


try {
        const docxBuffer = await generateDocx(...);

        if (filetype === 'pdf') {
            libre.convert(docxBuffer, 'pdf', undefined, (err, pdfBuffer) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    res.send(pdfBuffer);
                }
            });
        } else if (filetype === 'docx') {
            res.send(docxBuffer);
        }

        logger.info('Sent file buffer to the client', { filetype });
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Error during file creation', { filetype, error: error.message });
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }


// Your docxtemplater generator:

import Docxtemplater from 'docxtemplater';

function generateDocx(...): Promise<Buffer> {
    const content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'your-template.docx'), 'binary');

    const zip = new PizZip(content);
    const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {
        paragraphLoop: true,
        linebreaks: true,
    });
    doc.render({
       /// your template params
    });

    const buffer = doc.getZip().generate({
        type: 'nodebuffer',
        compression: 'DEFLATE',
    });

    return buffer;
}
```